# Error in dry : different keys in tuple and record

Tags: smart-contracts, tezos-client, blockchain, ligo

I am trying to dry-run one contract on online Ligo IDE,

Access function :

```
main
```

Parameters :

```
(10n, ("tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx" : address))
```

The logo code is compiling fine and I don't think there is any problem in the code but in the way I am passing the parameters as the error is :

**Error**

```
Error: ligo: in file "", line 0, character 0 to line 1, character 57. different keys in tuple and record: Expected these two types to be the same, but they're different (one is a tuple and the other is a record) {"a":"( nat * address )","b":"record[amount -> nat , tr_to -> address]"}
```

Can someone please help me in sending the parameters rightly.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update:
I converted my parameters to this: 
```Mint {amount= 10n; tr_to= ("tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx" : address)}```
and it started working!

Comment: Please post as answer and mark your answer as accepted so the system will mark your question “answered”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

I converted my parameters to this: Mint {amount= 10n; tr_to= ("tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx" : address)} and it started working!